# how to assign a vanity url to an express site

Tags: node.js, express

this network is just running locally. at the moment, users access the system by typing something like http://192.168.3.1:9093, but i'd like them to access something like: http://mysite:9093 (i understand i can't really get around the port being in the url). here is a bit of my head:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , fs = require('fs')

server.listen(9093);   

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client_app.html');
});

app.get('/2', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client_app2.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a node.js problem, this is a domain name question. That being said this article may be useful: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server Specifically the third heading. It just says

> - It’s perfectly valid to resolve a domain-name to a local LAN IP address.

So you will have to buy a domain name and set it's resolution to your local ip.

Comment: so then i guess i can set the 'domain' using some sort of hosts file on mac, thank you

Comment: i experimented with this. I found that I could tweak the hosts file and set my own domain. but when users connect to my computer remotely over the node network, that 'domain' doesn't hold up.